# How I can retrieve encryption keys for my IPsec/L2TP session?

Tags: kernel, ipsec

I'm investigating IPsec protocols stack with wireshark. If I need to decrypt tunnel's traffic, I use `ip xfrm state` command, which returns all needed stuff. During `ip` source code investigation, I discovered that encryption keys are retrieved from kernel via `NETLINK`. So, I was wondering if there is any other way to get this info from kernel bypassing the `NETLINK`? Perhaps, there is some `ioctl` to do this. I would like to know where in the kernel code these keys are stored.

Answer (score 0):

The two main interfaces I know about are:

- netlink (which you already mention) - the linux-native option since ~2.6, enabled via the XFRM_USER kernel config-option
- pfkey (for compatibility with tools ported from KAME) - enabled via the NET_KEY kernel config-option

See [here](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_configure_the_Linux_kernel/net/xfrm) for a howto-reference about those.

In terms of userland tools, as far as I've understood it, the iproute2 tool "ip" and its "xfrm" subcommand are the newer/better way to manually manipulate ipsec SADs and SPDs on linux, as a thin-layer over the netlink interface to the xfrm module, while the "setkey" tool uses the pfkey interface (to the same module) for compatibility (and on other systems like the BSDs). I think you will not really ever (or very rarely?) on linux find a need to use the pfkey interface if you can already talk over the netlink interface other than for compatibility with existing code.

Here are some examples ([1](http://www.racoon2.wide.ad.jp/ml/racoon2-users/201406/msg1041.html), [2](https://sourceforge.net/p/ipsec-tools/mailman/ipsec-tools-devel/thread/476F7300.8060307@iki.fi/)) of developers communicating about handling communication with both interfaces (in my experience they are notoriously badly, and sometimes just not, documented - and I've had to work stuff out by reading the source of the xfrm modules on several occasions).

The only other ways I could think of to interface with the xfrm module would be reading data [from /proc/net/xfrm_* files](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/xfrm_proc.txt) (depending on the kernel version and configuration those may or may not be present), hooking it with ftrace/kprobes/etc, or by writing your own kernel module to interact directly with the xfrm structs directly. I suspect that last option is nearly always a bad idea though.